# Ideas for color blind friendly presentation

Tags: beamer, color, accessibility

I'm creating a beamer presentation and would like to highlight some concepts using color, but still be friendly to all color blindness flavors. I do not want to be restricted to colors that are distinguishable by anyone, as they usually are not so many (nor that nice looking). Therefore, my approach revolves around using symbols. I've come up with two ideas so far:

[image: Idea 1]

I don't like the first so much because the shapes around the text look a bit heavy, specially the star shaped one. Also, there are not so many clearly distinct shapes that can be used to circle text and have a similar looking symbol.

[image: Idea 2]

I think the second is quite neat. My problem with it is that sometimes I do not want to use the space above the text to show symbols, and overlapped under-braces can be quite confusing.

I'm welcoming any ideas and thoughts on how to guarantee that my presentation will be color blind friendly. Which other approaches have you people thought of?

Thanks in advance!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,tikzmark,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
        \centering
        \tikzmark{start1}Concept A\tikzmark{end1}
        \tikzmark{start2}
           Concept B\tikzmark{start3} Concept C\tikzmark{end3}
        \tikzmark{end2}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[draw,line width=2pt,cyan,ellipse,inner ysep=12pt,fit={($(pic cs:start1)+(0.2,0)$) ($(pic cs:end1)+(-0.3,0)$)}] {};
        \node[draw,line width=2pt,purple,rectangle,inner ysep=24pt,fit={($(pic cs:start2)+(0.1,0)$) (pic cs:end2)}] {};
        \node[draw,line width=1.2pt,black,starburst, starburst points=16, starburst point height=6,inner ysep=10pt, inner xsep=2pt,fit={($(pic cs:start3)+(0.45,0.05)$) ($(pic cs:end3)+(-0.2,0.05)$)}] {}; 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    
    \vspace{2cm}
    \textcolor{black}{$\bigstar$ Summarize concept C}    
    
    \textcolor{cyan}{$\bullet$ Summarize concept A}
    
    \textcolor{purple}{$\blacksquare$ Summarize concept B}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
     \centering 
     $\textcolor{cyan}{\underbrace{\textcolor{black}{\text{Concept A}}}_{\bullet}}
     \overbrace{\text{Concept B} 
         \underbrace{\text{Concept C}}_{\bigstar}
     }^{\textcolor{purple}{\blacksquare}}$
    
    
    \vspace{2cm}
    \textcolor{black}{$\bigstar$ Summarize concept C}    
    
    \textcolor{cyan}{$\bullet$ Summarize concept A}
    
    \textcolor{purple}{$\blacksquare$ Summarize concept B}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a site somewhere that lets you upload an image and test for color-blindness safety. But also this: https://davidmathlogic.com/colorblind/#%23D81B60-%231E88E5-%23FFC107-%23004D40 is quite useful

Comment: There are also many sites online that talk about choosing good colors in relatation to color blind

Comment: I like the idea of focusing on the use of symbols or icons to communicate that things belong together, instead of (just) colour. Way back in the days when we used to have to print academic journal articles out instead of getting the PDFs, I used to love it when an author had gone to the effort of using different symbols on plots for different data series. But, I wonder if this is really a 'tex question (tex is implementation) and might actually be a good one for e.g. https://ux.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Rmano nice site! but that would count as being restricted to certain colors.

Comment: @AndyClifton nice, I did not know that community! I know people who still print articles in black and white and they are indeed always happy with the different symbols xD